# ElasticSearch analyzer with significance of terms

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize, analyzer

Here is my goal :

aggregate based on some text.

Lets do some examples:

> management consulting --- consulting ( these should be aggregated with "consult" or "consulting")
>
> data and analytics ---- analytics ( these should be aggregated with "analytics")
>
> buisness management--- buisness intelligence (" these should not be aggregated at all, they are different"

a sample input is as follows :

```
row 1 : management consulting,data and analytics,buisness intelligence
row 2 :consulting, analytics,buisness management
```

my analyzer is currently as follows:

```
"settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "category_analysis": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "comma_token",
                    "filter": ["lowercase", "english_stop"]
                }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "comma_token": {
                    "type": "pattern",
                    "pattern": ","
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "english_stop": {
                    "type": "stop",
                    "stopwords": "_english_"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Which basically takes all my input, separates by commas, and removes any stopwords..

The challenge is that if I split by everything

> ( Buisness Intelligence) => (Buisness,Intelligence)

, then I am losing the context and thus importance of the second part in this case. It would, however, work for

> (Data And Analytics) => (Data,Analytics)

.

Thus, is there any good way to go about achieving this task ? I am not sure if there is an easy way to do it, as i would presume that some machine learning may need to be used to understand that

> (Data And Analytics) => (Data,Analytics)

is good, but

> ( Buisness Intelligence) => (Buisness,Intelligence)

is not good.